# C# alternative for PHP function date('Y-m-d)

Tags: c#, php

What's the easiest way to generate a date string like in PHP with C#/.NET?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("yy-MM-dd"));
```

Answer (score 4):

[String Format for DateTime C#](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)